# How to isolate Menu Inflation to only two items?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, menu

I am trying to isolate my menu inflation to only two items. I have six items total. When one item is clicked, I want the first menu to come up. When the other item is clicked, I want the second menu to come up.

The way my code is now, the first menu comes up when you click three of the six items. The second menu comes up when you click the other three of the six items.

How do I make it so the first menu only comes up when one specific item is clicked, and the second menu comes up when the other specific item is clicked? Here is my code right now.

```
package com.carouseldemo.main;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



     @Override
      public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    if (flag)
       {
           menu.add("Product 1");
           menu.add("Product 2");
       }
       else 
       {
           menu.add("context");
           menu.add("menu");

       }
         super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

      }
     boolean flag=false;


        /** Called when the activity is first created.
         * @return */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio);
    mp.start();
    Carousel carousel = (Carousel)findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    registerForContextMenu (carousel);
    carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

         @Override           
        public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {       
                          if (flag)
                          {
                              flag=false;
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              flag=true;
                          }
                          registerForContextMenu(view); 
                          openContextMenu (view);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                            String.format("%s has been clicked",
                                            ((CarouselItem)parent.getChildAt(position)).getName()),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                            
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,
                            View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

    });



    carousel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

                    public void onItemSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                    final TextView txt = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.selected_item));

                            switch(position){
                            case 0:
                                    txt.setText("The cat (Felis catus), also known as the domestic cat or housecat to distinguish it from other felids and felines, is a small, usually furry, domesticated, carnivorous mammal that is valued by humans for its companionship and for its ability to hunt vermin and household pests. Cats have been associated with humans for at least 9,500 years, and are currently the most popular pet in the world. Owing to their close association with humans, cats are now found almost everywhere in the world.");
                                    break;
                            case 1:
                                    txt.setText("The hippopotamus (Hippopotamus amphibius), or hippo, from the ancient Greek for \"river horse\" (á¼±Ï€Ï€Î¿Ï€ÏŒÏ„Î±Î¼Î¿Ï‚), is a large, mostly herbivorous mammal in sub-Saharan Africa, and one of only two extant species in the family Hippopotamidae (the other is the Pygmy Hippopotamus.) After the elephant, the hippopotamus is the third largest land mammal and the heaviest extant artiodactyl.");
                                    break;
                            case 2:
                                    txt.setText("A monkey is a primate, either an Old World monkey or a New World monkey. There are about 260 known living species of monkey. Many are arboreal, although there are species that live primarily on the ground, such as baboons. Monkeys are generally considered to be intelligent. Unlike apes, monkeys usually have tails. Tailless monkeys may be called \"apes\", incorrectly according to modern usage; thus the tailless Barbary macaque is called the \"Barbary ape\".");
                                    break;
                            case 3:
                                    txt.setText("A mouse (plural: mice) is a small mammal belonging to the order of rodents. The best known mouse species is the common house mouse (Mus musculus). It is also a popular pet. In some places, certain kinds of field mice are also common. This rodent is eaten by large birds such as hawks and eagles. They are known to invade homes for food and occasionally shelter.");
                                    break;
                            case 4:
                                    txt.setText("The giant panda, or panda (Ailuropoda melanoleuca, literally meaning \"black and white cat-foot\") is a bear native to central-western and south western China.[4] It is easily recognized by its large, distinctive black patches around the eyes, over the ears, and across its round body. Though it belongs to the order Carnivora, the panda's diet is 99% bamboo.");
                                    break;
                            case 5:
                                    txt.setText("Rabbits (or, colloquially, bunnies) are small mammals in the family Leporidae of the order Lagomorpha, found in several parts of the world. There are eight different genera in the family classified as rabbits, including the European rabbit (Oryctolagus cuniculus), cottontail rabbits (genus Sylvilagus; 13 species), and the Amami rabbit (Pentalagus furnessi, an endangered species on Amami ÅŒshima, Japan)");
                                    break;
                            }

                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent) {
                    }

    }
    );

}

}
```

Comment: This cannot be solved by using if(boolean) then and else then. Keep track of which items where pressed and show menu accordingly

Comment: Yes, I need help solving this. It's part of my question, can you show me or help me on how to do this?

Comment: Yes, I will help you but something is not really clear. Can you confirm or adjust this scenario: item1 is clicked -> show menu1, item2 is clicked -> show menu2, item3 is clicked -> show menu3, ... etc. Is it like that or?

Comment: @LuluR I would recommend posting a more self-contained example. This example does not compile due to your custom classes meaning it's harder to understand what you're talking about. You also mention two menus and 6 items but it's hard to find them in the code (at least for me). The code BTW is a mess (formatting-wise).

Comment: Yes, exactly like that user1281750. When item1 is clicked, show menu1. When item2 is clicked, show menu2. When item3 is clicked, show menu3. Right now, I have six items. Three of the items open menu1, the other three open menu2. I need it to be exactly like you said user128175. @andr. I know the code is a mess, I'm just a beginner. Should I edit this question or make another?

Comment: I have changed the code to try to make it look more presentable. I apologize for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. If I understand you correctly, you simply want to assign an individual context menu to each item in the `Carousel` class. (Later I assume that `Carousel` is a subclass of `AdapterView` because its the only class known to me that uses `OnItemSelectedListener` handler.)

To do this, first take advantage of the fact that your `Carousel`, upon showing context menu, will pass you extra information in the context menu listener. You can extract item position to which the context menu should apply and create the menu according to that position. To do this you must change the `onCreateContextMenu()` handler:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // Just prepare ourself for unexpected arguments...
    if (menuInfo == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (!(menuInfo instanceof AdapterContextMenuInfo)) {
        return;
    }
    AdapterContextMenuInfo mi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
    switch (mi.position) {
    case 0:
        menu.add("cat menu");
        break;
    case 1:
        menu.add("hippopotamus menu");
        break;
    case 2:
        menu.add("monkey menu");
        break;
    case 3:
        menu.add("mouse menu");
        break;
    case 4:
        menu.add("panda menu");
        break;
    case 5:
        menu.add("rabbit menu");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

Try it and tell me if that is what you wanted. The rest of the code stays the same.

Comment: There's just one small error I can't figure out. I updated the code in my question to the current code I am using now. On super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo); an error reads: "The method onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu, View, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo) is undefined for the type object.

Comment: Paste the code to pastebin! I suspect you pasted it somewhat wrong, since it should end up in type `MainActivity` *not* `object`.

Comment: no no, you have already method `onCreateContextMenu` at the beginning of your `Activity` code! You were supposed to replace that code of that method with the code from my answer.

Comment: I have changed the code in my question back to it was originally, before I tried to put your code in. When I try to put your code in, there are other errors, so I must not be pasting it right. Can you please use the code in my question, and link me to a pastebin showing where you put the code correctly?

Comment: Changed the first method to my version http://pastebin.com/k8WfRGbp I couldn't fully test it since I don't have the code of your custom classes e.g. `Carousel`.

Comment: I ran the program. Only the toast messages are popping up, no menus are coming up.

Comment: Then I give up. Provide a smaller example code which others like me can compile at home to see what's exactly wrong.

Comment: Here is the source code, if it would help: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=146145

Comment: Here is the source as well if you prefer. http://code.google.com/p/android-carousel-demo/source/browse/#svn%2FCarouselDemo%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Comment: In addition, could the problem possibly be that there is no Menu Inflater within the code?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with that. The code (as always) lead me to a solution: the `CarouselAdapter` contains its own version of `AdapterContextMenuInfo`. The code I gave you is correct, you only have to change from `import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;` to `import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.AdapterContextMenuInfo;`. Full source here: http://pastebin.com/FLRCzV23 Tested - working. *That's why* we always ask to show the code :)

Comment: The toast are still only coming up for me, no menus are coming up. The menus came up for you when you tested it?

Comment: Yes. Do you know how to invoke *context* menu? You touch and *hold* your finger until menu pops up. Touch and hold a finger on the cat for example.

Comment: Thank you!! You went above and beyond to help me. The only thing is, do you know how to invoke the menu the instance the item is touched? Also, do you have a Paypal account? I would like to make a donation to you next time I get paid.

Comment: Also, what would I have to do to open a ListView instead of a Context Menu? Would that take a little editing, or a lot of coding? If it takes a lot of coding, can I use a context menu like a List?

Comment: Forget the donation :) Just *accept* and *upvote* answer if it helped you so that others can benefit from them. Showing context menu after touching an item requires you to programmatically show it in the item click listener. It's two lines marked with a comment here: http://pastebin.com/7FwvMFeQ

Comment: @LuluR it would take some time and code, but please - don't ask several questions in one. Start a new question if you have one. SO is designed for 1 question/1 post format.

Comment: Okay, I opened a new question and your code for an instant context menu worked once again. Thank you for your help.